# Javascript - Template Literals - Ternary Operation

Tags: javascript, console.log, template-literals

Ok, so what I'm trying to do is, I have a `isVisible` variable that is assigned to a function that figures out if which element I'm scrolling over when I'm navigating my page. I need to use the `isVisible` variable to check and log a msg depending on where I'm at on the page

For example, `isVisible` at the top of the page, log `X`, `isVisible` is at the middle of the page, log `Y`, `isVisible` is at the bottom of the page, log `Z`.

`isVisible` is a function that checks where the `trgt` is on the page.

`let isVisible = isScrolledIntoView(trgt);`

```
console.log(`element index ${index} is now ${isVisible ? '"X"': (isVisible ? "Y" : "Z")}`);
```

How would I rearrange this to make sense?

Comment: Checking `isVisible` twice makes no sense, since "Y" will never run. You'd need some other variable you check there.

Comment: Both your ternaries -- the first one and the nested one -- are using `isVisible` as their condition check... So basically you'll only ever get `X` or `Z`; `Y` is inaccessible...

Comment: Ah, how would I change it to where I can get 3 options, not sure how to do that with a ternary operator

Comment: By using a different variable for the second conditional.

Comment: The ternary form is fine, but if you have a single conditional check, it can only be truthy or falsy-- it can't represent a third state.  Using two conditions would allow you to represent three (actually four) different states.

Comment: Ok, so what I'm trying to do is, I have a `isVisible` variable that is assigned to a function that figures out if which element I'm scrolling over when I'm navigating my page. I need to use the `isVisible` variable to check and log a msg depending on where I'm at on the page

Comment: For example, `isVisible` at the top of the page, log `X`, `isVisible` is at the middle of the page, log `Y`, `isVisible` is at the bottom of the page, log `Z`.

Comment: Why not use intermediary variables instead of making the next developer to look at this want to pull their hair out trying to decipher what you are doing?  Keep the template literal lean.

Comment: I agree, I'd down to keep it as simple as possible, just not sure how to use a ternary operator based off of 3 conditionals

Comment: I believe @zero298 's point is _don't_ use the ternary operator based off three conditionals-- use lose the ternary and use `if...else` statements instead.

Comment: ah gotcha, yeah i'll probably change it up

Answer (score 2):

If you *really* want to use a ternary operator, you might assign a number/string to isVisible (which you'd then call something else probably) rather than a Boolean, and use `visible = someNumber/someString` in the ternary:

```js
const index = 1;
const visible = "bottom";

console.log(`element index ${index} is now ${visible === "top"
  ? '"X"' 
  : visible === "middle"
    ? "Y"
    : "Z"}`
);
```

But it seems in your case it's definitely preferred to use a switch/if statement in combination with numbers (or strings if you can come up with clear definitions) in case you need more positions on your page:

```js
const index = 1;
const visible = 3;

switch (visible) {
  case 1:
    console.log( `Element index ${index} is now visible at A` );
    break;

  case 2:
    console.log( `Element index ${index} is now visible at B` );
    break;

  case 3:
    console.log( `Element index ${index} is now visible at C` );
    break;

  case 4:
    console.log( `Element index ${index} is now visible at D` );
    break;

  default:
    console.log( "Element is now in the void" );
    break;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate that, I followed your ternary example and am not only getting one conditional being triggered

Answer (score 0):

```
let checkStatement = isVisible === id-10 ? `Column with id ${id-10} started to become visible on the page` : isVisible === id-50  ? `Column with id  ${id-50} is now more than 50% visible on the page` : `Column with id ${id-40} is now fully visible on the page`
```

Change the conditions to what suits your question and it should be fine

Comment: Why are you interpolating the condition check into a string?